# Extracting type from object unions

Tags: typescript

In the code below, is it possible to 'flatten' `Foo` such that it returns `{ A?: string; B? number }`

```js
type Foo = { A: string } | { B: number }

type Flatten<
  T,
  Keys extends keyof T = T extends any ? keyof T : never,
> = { [K in Keys]?: T[K] }


type Bar = Flatten<Foo> 
// { A?: unknown; B? unknown }, but is it possible to return `{ A?: string; B? number }`?
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBBAXFAzsAJwEsA7AcygF8oAfNKAIRxIFcBbAIwgKoFgAoAaEiwANgENgwCCQA8AqFAAqAGgVQA0hBC4oEAB7SSAE10BrbXABmy5LYNHTUcSRBQA-FAshrt5hAA3bjV+AD47dABtDShSTW1cAF13HCVoxL5BLOFoBnEeFBgJKRlZeDhwgHpK+gwUqBYSMxI4AHcSNkZPRua2kiogA)

Comment: It could be like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5A89N) but what do you want `Flatten<{a: string} | {a: number}>` to be? Presumably `{a: string | number}` and *not* `{a?: string | number}`, right?

Comment: I'm assuming [this operation](https://tsplay.dev/m0zGPw) where any union member implicitly gets optional properties of type `never` for any unmentioned key is what you really want.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, wow, that's great.  I thought this was going to be insoluble.   Thank you.

Comment: So is that second one what you're looking for?  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance (it is my bedtime now so I will probably do so in ~8 or 9 hours)

Comment: Both work for my use case, but the second one is more robust.  Thanks, sleep well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting the `Flatten<T>` operation as what would happen if you collapsed a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types to a single object type, *if object types were sealed or "exact"* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)) and prohibited excess properties.

Currently object types are open or extendible, and excess properties are allowed.  A value of the `{a: string}` type definitely has a `string`-valued `a` property, but it might also have any other property, such as a `string`-valued `b` property.  The mere absence of `b` in the type definition doesn't imply that it is missing.  If you ask the compiler what property type will be present at the `b` key of `{a: string}` (and you manage to circumvent the detection that tells you you're probably making a mistake, as you did in your definition of `Keys extends keyof T = T extends any ? keyof T : never`), it will tell you that it's [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), because it could be literally anything. And that means the `b` property of `{a: string} | {b: number}` is also of type `unknown`, because "`number` or ‍♂️" is the same as just "‍♂️".  So `{a: string} | {b: number}` flattens to something like `{a?: unknown, b?: unknown}`, which is not what you want.

There's currently no way to express that all unspecified keys should prohibited so that you could write `Exact<{a: string}> | Exact<{b: number}>` and then collapse that to a single object which would presumably look like `Exact<{a?: string, b?: number}>`.  If you want to prohibit a *particular* key, the closest you can get is to make it an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  So `{a: string}` *might* have a `b` property, but `{a: string, b?: never}` *definitely does not*.  Well, depending on your compiler settings, it might have a property but the value will be `undefined`.

But since we know all of the keys that are mentioned in `T`, this gives us enough of a handle to implement what you're looking for. We need `Flatten<T>` to essentially

1. get all the keys from all union members of `T`; call this `AllKeys<T>`.
2. extend each union member of `T` to prohibit all unmentioned keys from `AllKeys<T>`
3. collapse the new union into a single object type

So if `T` is `{a: string} | {b: number}` that would look like:

1. `AllKeys<T>` should be `"a" | "b"`
2. Extend each union member of `T` to prohibit unmentioned keys:

   - Extend `{a: string}` to `{a: string; b?: never}` to prohibit `b`
   - Extend `{b: number}` to `{a?: never; b: number}` to prohibit `a`
3. Collapse `{a: string; b?: never} | {a?: never; b: number}` to the single object type `{a?: string; b?: number}`.

That's the plan, now let's implement it.

---

First let's implement `AllKeys<T>`:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
```

This is a fairly straightforward [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that collects keys from each member of `T` and unites them together.

Then we can write `ProhibitExtra<T, K>` which extends an object type `T` to prohibit any unmentioned keys from `K` (where unmentioned keys are `Exclude<K, keyof T>` using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)):

```
type ProhibitExtra<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T & { [P in Exclude<K, keyof T>]?: never };
```

That works by intersecting `T` with optional `never`-typed properties for each unmentioned key in `K`.

Then we can write `ExactifyUnion<T>` which distributes `ProhibitExtra<T, K>` over  unions in `T`, and where `K` is `AllKeys<T>` for the original non-distributed `T`.  That is, we don't want to write `ProhibitExtra<T, AllKeys<T>>` directly, since you want to distribute the `T` on the left but not the `T` on the right.  This adds a little complication, and one way to deal with it is to use a [default generic type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) `K` to access `T` before it's distributed:

```
type ExactifyUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey = AllKeys<T>> =
  T extends unknown ? ProhibitExtra<T, K> : never
```

And finally we can write `Flatten<T>`, which applies `ExactifyUnion<T>` to get a new union, and then collapses it to a single object type:

```
type Flatten<T> = Omit<ExactifyUnion<T>, never>;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) does *not* distribute over unions (which is intentional as per [microsoft/TypeScript#46361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46361)) and is thus an easy way to do a single identity [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that doesn't distribute.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
type F1 = Flatten<{ a: string } | { b: number }> 
// type F1 = { a?: string; b?: number }
```

That's what you wanted! Note that when a property is present in all union members, it should not be optional:

```
type F2 = Flatten<{ a: string } | { a: number }> 
// type F2 { a: string | number }
```

Here is a sampling of what happens in the face of optional/required properties which are present in some/all union members:

```
type F3 = Flatten<
  { a?: string, b: number, c: boolean, d?: Date } |
  { c: string, d?: number, e: boolean, f?: Date }>
/* type F3 = {
    a?: string;
    b?: number;
    c: string | boolean;
    d?: number | Date;
    e?: boolean;
    f?: Date;
} */
```

Looks good to me!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCapQCuFA1hQPYDuFUA-FIyiwDNCUAFxQKEAG4QATgG4AsAChloSFAAKMlgAsAlgCM9wAKJkZAQywAaKImJlKNTdsgzQyELjzKowgGRQAN5QANoaUHqcZgDGcHRUEOiItnwggoTYALpcYhLSMlAAvooqSmrQZhYxwHoCIACqFHosFDZ2DuTUtFosbh4o+LAInhg43r7CpF3ODMzsnDy9+kam5laYtoi4eVKyyqrg0ABicBbAXVjeUADyALbG6FU1dY3NrVe2+bLYpYfqxwAjENTudLiELGJUMAZFEAObFKAAH2CUAMeTodwMsmKuAA9HjURZclBobCKHC5GiSRRMdjCkV-icAEwgs4XSjoCFQmHwxEo7niOk4or4wmCsl8lG0rEiplQY4AZjZYM5kwhJMlFNs6KFspkthiYgMLBYcAgFgotioJIAIudoEVkeqoEbSbztVAbRj9bYIMbTebLbYBHaHcVlNhlHiAFRQCoK5U+JR+PzEnnkymTPwGGnC+TZ10ZqVowMWiilVNevP65FQe3kSupiAkk1m8tNvyhsQNiClJ0xvEHMrKIA)

Comment: Wow, a great answer: easy to read an understand.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this does the trick:

```
type Foo = { A: string } | { B: number }

type Flatten<
  T
> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }


type Bar = Flatten<Foo> 

const L: Bar = {A: 'test', B: 1}
```

Comment: What "trick" does this do? Your `Bar` is identical to `Foo` so you haven't done much. Can you [edit] to elaborate on what you're doing and how it fixes the issue?  Unless the trick is that it *doesn't*, in which case I guess you tricked me! 